# Binning values in Python3

Tags: python-3.x

Say I have the following txt file

```
Distances    Counts
1             5
2             5 
3             9
4             10
9             10
10            10
11            5
14            5
20            1
21            1
23            2
```

I would like a way to bin according to the first column and sum the second column.
The correct output if you use a bin of 5 would be

```
0-5     29
5-10    20
10-15   10
15-20   20
20-25   3
```

or just

```
5       29
10      20
15      10
20      20
25      3
```

i tried

```
binfile = open('distances.txt', 'r')
binsize = 5
summar = 0
binsize2 = binsize
for line in binfile:
    line = line.strip().split('\t')
    distance = int(line[0])
    counts = int(line[1])
    if distance <= binsize2:
        summar += counts
    else:
        print(str(binsize2)+'\t'+str(summar))
        binsize2 = binsize2 + binsize
        summar = counts
```

but it doesn't print the last bin. Any suggestions?

Comment: Yes, do another final iteration after the loop ;)

Comment: Yes that is a solution. I was hoping for a different approach like a built-in function or something.